# How to qualify a 90% success without sounding to brag about it?

Tags: word-choice

I need to refer to predictions I made that were not a 100% success, but a 90+% success.

I first wrote "with some success" but a native english speaker (I am not) reviewed it and told me "some success" did not sound very successful.

How I express the results were good enough for me to be completely satisfied by them without being perfect, and not sound to be bragging about it?

Comment: What's wrong with "with over 90% success rate"?

Comment: It is about a scientific subject where the math could be done, but would need a lot of effort. So I don't want to bring a precise number that is just a quick estimation.

Comment: You scored better than nine out of ten.

Comment: @DirtyHenry How about saying sonething along the lines of "with an honorable (or estimable) success rate?" http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/honorable

Comment: There are other adjectives besides "some".  "Considerable" may be appropriate, eg.

Comment: "with a *xxx* probability of success", where xxx may be "substantial", "high", "very high", "near total".

Comment: "Ma'am, I'm pleased to report that your husband's heart surgery was 90% successful."

Comment: @DougWarren: funny. Not helpful. :)

Comment: @DougWarren - And 90% of the people from the old folks home made it across the street without being struck and killed.  A pretty high success rate!

Comment: "A new technology manages to capture 90% of the sun energy". Right now 20% is considered excellent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you're talking about personal success some people may perceive you as *bragging* or immodest regardless of how you present yourself. This is probably more true when referring to a perfect or near perfect performance.

I would suggest an honest and accurate characterization using objective and straightforward language.

Consider these phrases:

- *a high rate of success*
- *a high degree of success*

...and since we're talking about predictions:

- *a high rate of accuracy*
- *a high rate of precision*
- *a near-perfect record*

Answer (score 1):

If you are actually objectively correct 90/100 times, then just use the 90% figure.

If you are being subjective, I would say "great success" or "successful more times than not."

Answer (score 0):

You could call it a "high rate of success" or "highly successful". Or, your predictions were made with "good/excellent accuracy". Your colleague is correct, saying "some success" suggests fairly mediocre performance.